# Concurrent Android network requests

Tags: android, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

I am building a fragment in Android which displays some data kept on a server. As long as the user is on this fragment, I would like to poll the server every x seconds. Additionally, I would like to stop this procedure once the user navigates away from this fragment. Is the optimum solution to this problem to use coroutines or a thread? Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling is never a good option as you will keep on wasting resources while the server might have no new data to supply. However, if you are still keen on doing that, you can use any of the choices, i.e. coroutines and thread. In thread, you'd have to manage its lifecycle yourself whereas in coroutine you don't have to worry about anything as `CoroutineScope` takes care of all that for you. One incentive of going with `Coroutines` would be the supply of `operators` you can use on your `flows`, `map` and `switchMap` for instance.

A better solution would be to make use of `SNS` or `firebaseRemoteMessagingService` that can notify your application client, upon which you can request the server.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was wondering if threads are as viable to use now that coroutines are an option

Comment: Threads are and always will be viable to use. Its one of the core API's and is a direct handle to create threads in your application. Plus using Kotlin coroutines is an external dependency on kotlin's coroutines library. However, a lot of people do not have clear concepts when it comes to how to properly use threads. If you believe that you fall in that region than it is better to use the coroutines library as it protects you from certain situations. You still, however, need to worry about exception handling with coroutines (google CoroutineCancellationException).